# Getting an error while trying to use insertOne() function in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to learn MongoDB from a youtube tutorial.

`https://youtu.be/fbYExfeFsI0`

But when I was trying to insert data into my collection the same way as she did in the video, I get an output like this:

> C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:452
> const error = this.closed ? new errors_1.PoolClosedError(this) : new errors_1.PoolClearedError(this);
> ^
>
> PoolClosedError [MongoPoolClosedError]: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool
> at ConnectionPool.processWaitQueue (C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:452:45)
> at ConnectionPool.close (C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:260:14)
> at Server.destroy (C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:128:21)
> at destroyServer (C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:445:12)
> at node:internal/util:364:7
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at destroyServer (node:internal/util:350:12)
> at C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:226:56
> at Function.from (<anonymous>)
> at Topology.close (C:\Users\komal\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:225:40) {
> address: 'ac-nw6d7vk-shard-00-01.ra2eh5p.mongodb.net:27017',
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
> }
>
> Node.js v18.12.0

**My code in app.js file:**

> ```
> const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
> async function main(){
>
> const uri = "mongodb+srv://netTheCoder:welcome@cluster0.ra2eh5p.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
> const client = new MongoClient(uri);
>
>
> try{
>     await client.connect();
>     createListing(client,{
>         name: "Hello Tower",
>         summary: "A buitiful mesmarising building in Switzerland",
>         bedroom: 30,
>         bathrooms: 28
>     })
>    
> } catch(e){
>     console.log(e);
> }finally{
>     await client.close();
> }
> }
>
> async function createListing(client,newListing){
>    const result = await client.db("SampleDatabase").collection("Names").insertOne(newListing);
> console.log(result);
> }
>
> main().catch(console.error);
> ```

I was trying to add data into a collection called Names in a database called SampleDatabase.

I tried changing databases and making new collections and also tried making new clusters. But none of it works. I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

An async function implicitly returns a promise. I'm pretty sure `createListing` is actually a promise you forgot to await. Just add
await in front of the `createListing` function.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
async function main(){

const uri = "mongodb+srv://netTheCoder:welcome@cluster0.ra2eh5p.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);


try{
    await client.connect();
    await createListing(client,{  // <--- notice the await here
        name: "Hello Tower",
        summary: "A buitiful mesmarising building in Switzerland",
        bedroom: 30,
        bathrooms: 28
    })
   
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}finally{
    await client.close();
}
}

async function createListing(client,newListing){
   const result = await client.db("SampleDatabase").collection("Names").insertOne(newListing);
console.log(result); //<--- implicitly returns a promise
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

These are my understanding as far as I know. Any folks can let me know if I'm wrong.

More information on MDN [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)